# How can I delete a determined row in Sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a `ListView`. I add single row in sqlite database by checking it.(`CheckBox`) At the same time I need to delete the row, which I've unchecked. I need the ID of the row which is stored in my table, due to which I can delete the row. How can I do it ? 
This is my `CheckBox` changing code in `Adapter`.

```
public class MainVacancyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

   private List<VacancyModel> vacancyModelList;
   private int resource;
   private LayoutInflater inflater;
   ArrayList<Boolean> isSelected;
   SQLHelper sqlHelper;

   public MainVacancyAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<VacancyModel> objects) {
       super(context, resource, objects);
       vacancyModelList = objects;
       this.resource = resource;
       sqlHelper = new SQLHelper(getContext());
       inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

       isSelected = new ArrayList<>(vacancyModelList.size());
       for (int i = 0; i < vacancyModelList.size(); i++) {
           isSelected.add(false);
       }
   }

   //Finding textViews and inserting data into them
   @Override
   public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
        holder.tvHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeader);
        holder.tvProfileName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvProfileName);
        holder.tvSalary = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSalary);
        holder.tvPostCr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPostCr);
        //holder.tvBody = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvBody);
        holder.cbxFav = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbxFav);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.cbxFav.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    }
       holder.tvHeader.setText(vacancyModelList.get(position).getHeader());
       holder.tvProfileName.setText(vacancyModelList.get(position).getProfileName());
    holder.tvSalary.setText(vacancyModelList.get(position).getSalary());
       holder.tvPostCr.setText(vacancyModelList.get(position).getPostCreated());
       //holder.tvBody.setText(vacancyModelList.get(position).getBody());

       holder.cbxFav.setChecked(isSelected.get(position));

       holder.cbxFav.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

               if (isChecked) {
                //inserting the data into Favourite Table in sql
                   isSelected.set(position, true);
                   sqlHelper.createFavouriteTable(vacancyModelList.get(position));
                   //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Added to favourite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               } else {
                   isSelected.set(position, false);
                   sqlHelper.deleteFromFavouriteDatabase(position);
                   //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Deleted from favourite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           }
       });

       return convertView;
   }

   static class ViewHolder {
       TextView tvHeader;
       TextView tvProfileName;
       TextView tvSalary;
       TextView tvPostCr;
       TextView tvBody;
       CheckBox cbxFav;
   }
}
```

method in `SQLHelper class`

```
public void deleteFromFavouriteDatabase(int rowID) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(FAVOURITE.TABLE_NAME, FAVOURITE.KEY_ID + " = " + rowID, null);
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Show full adapter class code

Comment: Are you passing entire VacancyModel object for createFavouriteTable method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place column of `Id` in `VacancyModel` and bind it then on Delete

```
int id = vacancyModelList.get(position).getId()
sqlHelper.deleteFromFavouriteDatabase(id);
```

Comment: The problem was, that there was no value ID in JSON file. After adding ID in JSON file, your method was used

Answer (score 0):

try change your delete statement to this:

`db.delete(FAVOURITE.TABLE_NAME, FAVOURITE.KEY_ID + "=?", new String[]{rowID});`

Answer (score 0):

Please change your getView() method by below :

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

ViewHolder holder = null;

if (convertView == null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
    holder.tvHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeader);
    holder.tvProfileName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvProfileName);
    holder.tvSalary = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSalary);
    holder.tvPostCr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPostCr);
    //holder.tvBody = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvBody);
    holder.cbxFav = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbxFav);

    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    holder.cbxFav.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
}


holder.cbxFav.setTag(vacancyModelList.get(position));



   holder.tvHeader.setText(vacancyModelList.get(position).getHeader());
   holder.tvProfileName.setText(vacancyModelList.get(position).getProfileName());
   holder.tvSalary.setText(vacancyModelList.get(position).getSalary());
   holder.tvPostCr.setText(vacancyModelList.get(position).getPostCreated());
   //holder.tvBody.setText(vacancyModelList.get(position).getBody());

   holder.cbxFav.setChecked(isSelected.get(position));

   holder.cbxFav.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

           if (isChecked) {
            //inserting the data into Favourite Table in sql
               isSelected.set(position, true);
       VacancyModel selectedModel = (VacancyModel) holder.cbxFav.getTag();


               sqlHelper.createFavouriteTable(selectedModel);
               //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Added to favourite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           } else {
               isSelected.set(position, false);
               //sqlHelper.deleteFromFavouriteDatabase(position);
               //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Deleted from favourite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              VacancyModel selectedModel = (VacancyModel) holder.cbxFav.getTag();
                  sqlHelper.deleteFromFavouriteDatabase(selectedModel.getId());

           }
       }
   });

   return convertView;
 }
```

Comment: sqlHelper.deleteFromFavouriteDatabase(selectedModel.getId()); "getId" is unavailable

Comment: put there your id field man I have put getId, you have to use your unique id there